# How can I remove a nested data If a specific key found similar in big JSON data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-loops

The simple way to filter is to loop them all, but trust me as I have very massive data looping is very time consuming and maybe not be very efficient way,

```
 [
  {
    "from_name": "Haio",
    "from_id": 183556205,
    "receiver_name": "Shubh M",
    "targeted_id": 78545445,
    "gift_value": '$56'
  },
  {
    "from_name": "Mr. A",
    "from_id": 54545455,
    "receiver_name": "haio",
    "targeted_id": 78545445,
    "gift_value": '$7'
  }]
```

What do I want to accomplish?

I just want to delete the dict If `targeted_id`is same

Comment: Can you show the loop you have tried and which is too slow?

Comment: So in this case, do you want to delete both entries as they have the same targetid or only one of them?  If it is only one of them, what one do you want to keep? Do you ultimately only want a list of distinct targetids?

Comment: What is your source of the data? is it a file, do you want to write a new file? Do you want to remove duplicates "in-place" or do you want to create a new list without the duplicates? What does "massive" mean?

Answer (score 0):

````
def remove_duplicates(lst, key=lambda x: x, acc=[], keys = []):
    if lst == []:
        return acc
    elif key(lst[0]) in keys:
        return remove_duplicates(lst[1:], key=key, acc=acc, keys=keys)
    else:
        return remove_duplicates(lst[1:], key=key, acc = acc + [lst[0]], keys=keys + [key(lst[0])])
```
````

Comment: Since the data is suggested to be "huge" I would not think that any solution based on recursion would work.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can load the whole dataset into memory, use pandas and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). By default, it will keep the first of each set of duplicate records. There is some overhead associated with creating a dataframe, but if there are lots of records to go through then dropping duplicates this way should be much faster than a python loop.

```
import pandas as pd
data =[
  {
    "from_name": "Haio",
    "from_id": 183556205,
    "receiver_name": "Shubh M",
    "targeted_id": 78545445,
    "gift_value": '$56'
  },
  {
    "from_name": "Mr. A",
    "from_id": 54545455,
    "receiver_name": "haio",
    "targeted_id": 78545445,
    "gift_value": '$7'
  }]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).drop_duplicates(subset=['targeted_id'])
print(df.to_json()) # or specify a file name to save it
```